# Find the number of group isomorphisms from the group $(\mathbb{Z}_3, +)$ to itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I have to find the number of isomorphisms from the group $( \mathbb{Z}_3, + )$ to itself.

I don't know of any procedure to do this so I basically just tried to guess functions until I cannot find anything else. I found that the functions:

$$f(x) = x$$

$$f(x) = \hat{2}x$$

are both bijective and they hold the equality:

$$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$

true for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. So I concluded that these are all the isomorphism from the group $(\mathbb{Z}_3, +)$ to itself, since I couldn't find any more functions to be bijective and satisfy that condition.

I checked the answer of the exercise and it agrees with me, saying that the correct answer is $2$ (meaning $2$ isomorphisms, I guess the ones I found).

> My question is this: Is there a more organized, general way of finding the answer to this question.

Guessing all the possible function seems *a bit* weird, there are infinite possibilities.

How do I know that I found the maximum number of isomorphisms and that I can stop? Is there a better strategy than guessing the functions and coming up with the answer?

Comment: there aren't infinitely many possibilities; an automorphism (isomorphism from group to itself) must map $0$ (additive identity) to $0$, and then $1$ could map to $1$ or $2$

Comment: A generator has to go to a generator.  There are $\phi(n)$ generators for $\Bbb Z_n$.  See @Shaun's answer.  This is the more general way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't an infinite number, for it to be a bijection, you have $3$ choices for $f(0)$, $2$ choices for $f(1)$, and then $f(2)$ is determined.

That is, your choices are

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 0,1,2$

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 0,2,1$

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 1,0,2$

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 1,2,0$

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 2,0,1$

$f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 2,1,0$

and then not all of these will respect the group operation, e.g. for $f(0), f(1), f(2)  = 2,1,0$, you have $f(0 + 1) = f(1) = 2$, but $f(0) + f(1) = 2 + 1 = 0$.

This is still a little brute force, but by observing, e.g. that $f(0) = 0$ is true for any group isomorphism, you narrow things down even more.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n),$$ where $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Can you please tell me what that sign between $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ and $U(n)$ means?

Comment: It means, @user1502, that ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)$ is isomorphic to $U(n)$ (as groups, which ought to be inferred from the context).